# Oracle GoldenGate real time replication to HDFS

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, hdfs, oracle-golden-gate

We need to replicate **all tables** from an **Oracle database** into **HDFS (hive)**, detecting changes from oracle in real-time.

We understand that the Oracle GoldenGate is the right tool to do this, but looking at this docs :
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/documentation/gg-java-adp-bigdata-hdfs-adp-2601138.pdf,
seems that the adapter for HDFS only stores the transaction log into HDFS as a list of operation done on the database,instead we need the entire database replicated.

There is a way to achieve that? We are still evaluating how to do it,so any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

GoldenGate is a "change data capture" replication solution.  That means it only replicate the "changed data", i.e., the delta generated by DML to your tables.

If you want to dump the entire database, assuming you meant to replicate each table and all the data in the table, you should use initial load Extract to generate the trail file, which will turn each record as an insert operation, then use GG BigData HDFS adapter to dump those data to HDFS.  However, that is only static data.  Almost like an ETL tool.